# Modules in yii - explain

Tags: php, module, yii

I'm having a hard time understanding modules in Yii. Can someone explain to me what their purpose is and what the come to add?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> A module is a self-contained software unit that consists of models, views, controllers and other supporting components. In many aspects, a module is similar to an application. The main difference is that a module cannot be deployed alone and it must reside inside of an application. Users can access the controllers in a module like they do with normal application controllers.

Answer (score 1):

To theoretically understand **What are Yii Modules** you will have to read  the official guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module , however there is no better way to practically understand coding than reading  good code. Check [yii-user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) which is a yii extension for registration and management users accounts.

The extension is basically a yii module and it's well documented so you get to know **What** & **How** modules do in real life.