# How to add extensions that developed as modules and behavior in ny yii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

How to add extensions that developed as  modules in  yii?
can any one explain extensions as Yii modules and extensions as Yii behavior

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578217/unable-to-add-yii-extension-to-my-project/12578491#12578491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your Q is a **duplicate** with this q: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008314/modules-in-yii-explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008314/modules-in-yii-explain/12008877#12008877)

regarding the "**How to Use Modules**" part. Modules are may be the easiest way there to extend yii, since all you need to do is [two tiny steps](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module#using-module):

1. Extract the code under base directory `/protected/modules`.
2. Declare the used module in the application configuration:

```
return array(
  ...
  'module' => ('moduleName', 'some argument', 'another argument'),
  ...
);
```

I haighly recommend taking a look at the docs above then [User-Module](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) (as code sample) to get a better understanding to yii modules.

As for "**Extending Yii by Behaviors**", i have been confused myself for a while about that, until i had a chance to use the [Multi-Lingual_Behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multilingual-behavior/#hh1)

There is no typical way for extending Yii with behaviors, simply because there are multiple options (as you can see in the docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use#behavior) & [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-behavior)) for using (attaching) behaviors to components (application, models, controllers, ...etc)

That said, most of yii-extensions there are supported with good `Usage` docs that are enough in most cases to get them working.